# Was Obi-Wan Kenobi patterned after Castañeda's Don Juan?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, george-lucas

Brian Jay Jones in his biography of George Lucas, *George Lucas: A Life* (2016), tells that in May 1975, while writing an early six-page synopsis of Star Wars, George Lucas read *The Teachings of Don Juan: A Yaqui Way of Knowledge*, a work of anthropology and Sci-Fi by American author Carlos Castañeda.

Then, in August 1975, Lucas finished a third draft of Star Wars, the first to feature a character named General Ben Kenobi. About him, Lucas wrote..."Old man can do magic, read minds, talk to things like Don Juan".

In Castaneda's book, Don Juan is a Yaqui sorcerer and shaman.

Comment: "About him, Lucas wrote..."Old man can do magic, read minds, talk to things like Don Juan"." Doesn't this answer your question in the affirmative?

Comment: @WiggotheWookie - Probably, but I don't think one unique recent book, after almost 50 years, should suffice as an authoritative source to confirm Kenobi's origin. It could be other references out there about this topic.

Comment: Obi-Juan Kenobi? Twist!

Comment: You appear to have Jones's book, so was there a footnote referencing his source for this?

Comment: @Spencer - I don't have the book. It is mentioned in a reissue of a special 2021 edition of Life magazine "George Lucas and the Making of Star Wars" 45th Anniversary.